# generator learns generating features in GAN

Tags: gan

In Image generation using GAN, what if image features are given as input instead of Image to the discriminator? will generator generates features?

Any kind of reference is helpfull

Comment: What do you mean by "image features"?

Comment: edges lines and any other features instead of an image directly

Comment: That definition would need to be differentiable, otherwise propagating discriminator gradients to the generator would be almost infeasible (not impossible, though)

Comment: @Firebug Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following GAN, where $\mathcal D$ is a discriminator and $\mathcal G$ is a generator.

$$\min_{\theta_\mathcal D, \theta_\mathcal G} \mathcal {L}_{\mathcal D}(\mathcal D(X),\mathcal D(\mathcal G(Z)))$$

$X$ represents batches of real data and $Z$ represents batches of random generated numbers.

If $X$ are "image features" as you defined them, *i.e.* description of lines and other geometric features, then yes, $\mathcal G$ can theoretically learn how to generate them.

This represents two issues, however: (1) you need to represent these features at once for the real images, with tensor notation, which invariably leads to loss of information, and (2) you need to reverse the process to check the quality of generated images.

Non purely convolutional architectures, such as Graph Neural Networks, may ameliorate the issues however (though I'm not sure how to represent a curved contour in a graph embedding).

Comment: Is the output of the generator is features of input data after training?

Comment: @SSVarshini yes, the generator will learn to generate whatever you feed as real data to the discriminator

Comment: In this case how to evaluate the generator. If we give Image input we can use the inception score to evaluate the generator